How to implement Routes location on Reacr router ^6.23.0 createBrowserRouter?
currently i am trying to transform below router into createBrowserRouter version
The purpose of this is to implement the navigation logic of the modal box (Modal). For example, you can open a post details page (such as /posts/:id) from a list page (such as /home) without leaving the current page, display the modal box (Modal), and retain the routing state of the background page .
const App = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const background = location.state?.backgroundLocation

  return (
    <>
      <Routes location={background ?? location}>
        <Route element={<DashboardLayout />} errorElement={<NotFound />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route element={<ModalLayout />}>
            <Route path="/posts/:id" element={<Post />}></Route>
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

my question is how to  implement <Routes location={background ?? location}> on createBrowserRouter?
current createBrowserRouter code is down below
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AuthProviderLayout />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <DashboardLayout />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <Home />
          },
          {
            element: <ModalLayout />,
            children: [
              {
                path: '/posts/:id',
                element: <Post />
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      }
    ]
  }
])

export default router


or should I write conditionals on DashboardLayout?
import { Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
const DashboardLayout = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const background = location.state?.backgroundLocation
  return (
    <>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}

export default DashboardLayout

In summary, the purpose of this setting is to support keeping the background page unchanged when the modal box is displayed, and to be able to return to the previous background page after closing the modal box. This is useful for scenarios where additional content needs to be displayed without reloading the entire page.
Thanks for watching! I'd really appreciate it if you could leave a comment and let me know your thoughts. Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly helpful.

The Data routers kind of handle the "Routes" abstraction for you, so I don't believe there's a way to do this using the Data routers. If you are not using Data APIs then there is also no need to use a Data router, the BrowserRouter will work just fine.
